# Batch file variable filenames and editing

Tags: windows, batch-file

Fairly new to the game and have spent many hours looking for help and examples. I've had a version of this working, although I want to streamline the process by having a single input file 'computer_listc.txt'. I basically want to read in a series of folders paths (from computer_listc.txt), and use parts of the path to write further cmd expressions.

My problem is that fname and comp_id are not being set properly. I want to make them equal to T (the filename), and then edit them.

fname needs to be the filepath with the first 12 characters removed. While comp_id needs to equal the computername specified in the filepath e.g.

```
fname = c_modelling\model\slave1
comp_id = VOSTRO460-1
```

Heres the script. Can you see my error??

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%T in ("C:\c_modelling\Model\cal21_cal\Computer_ListC.TXT") do (
set fname = %%T
ren fname "%fname%" "C:\%fname%:~12%"
set comp_id = %%T
%comp_id% = %{comp_id:0:12} 
mkdir %%T > NUL 2>&1
echo cd %fname% >\\%%T\beo_insC.cmd
echo beo >>\\%%T\beo_insC.cmd
robocopy c:\c_modelling\model\cal21_cal \\%%T\ /s /e
start cmd.exe /c psexec \\%comp_id% -c c:\c_modelling\model\cal21_cal\beo_insC.cmd
del \\%%T\beo_insC.cmd
)
```

Computer_ListC.txt contains the following file names: This will eventually have a long list of computer folder paths.

```
VOSTRO460-1\c_modelling\model\slave1
VOSTRO460-1\c_modelling\model\slave2
```

I'm creating a *.cmd file for use with 'psexec', as when I direct the process to a local computer, the path defaults to \system32.

Any assistance would be very helpful!!

Comment: While you've written this very well, you forgot to explain what the problem is, or to ask a question at all. Can you [edit] to do so? Thanks. :-)

Comment: Thanks Ken - Hope this is clearer :)

Comment: +1. Much clearer. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First issue is that SPACES in string `SET` statements are significant. The variablename AND the value assigned will both include any spaces, so `set fname = %%T` will set a variable named `"fname "`, not `"fname"` - and its value will contain the leading space before the value of `%%T`

Next is the perpetual delayed-expansion issue. Within a `block` (a sequence of parenthesised statements) any `%var%` will be replaced by its value at **PARSE** time - before execution of the loop begins.

To access the **RUN-TIME** value, you need to execute a `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` statement, and while `delayedexpansion` is invoked, `!var!` accesses the **RUN**-time variable value.

Note however that you cannot simply invoke `delayedexpansion` within a loop with impunity. There is a limit to the number you can have open at any one time, so you need to 'close the bracket' with an `ENDLOCAL` command (reaching logical End-Of-File is equivalent to an `ENDLOCAL`) and the downside is that `ENDLOCAL` restores the environment to its value when the matching `SETLOCAL` was invoked. For this reason, `SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` is normally executed at the start of the batch, usually after the `@echo off`

Next issue is

```
ren fname "%fname%" "C:\%fname%:~12%"
```

The rename command's syntax is `ren sourcename newname` - exactly two arguments, enclose any argument containing spaces in `"rabbit's ears"` Further, the destination name is a NAME only - not a path.

Then there's this:

```
%comp_id% = %{comp_id:0:12}
```

Assuming you've fixed this to remove the spaces in variablenames and that `comp_id` has been assigned the value `fred` and you've realised that you are dealing with the **RUN**-time value of `comp_id` then this would now appear as

```
!comp_id!=%{comp_id:0:12}
```

which Batch would interpret as

```
fred=%{comp_id:0:12}
```

and promptly give up.

What you are probably expecting to do is

```
set comp_id=!comp_id:~0,12!
```

that is, set `comp_id` to the **RUN**-time value of comp_id, from the first character (`0`) for `12` characters.

Comment: Excellent, thanks Peter. She's all working now. This is what happens when Fortran coders have a crack at batch file scripting. Cheers